# Apache camel as a reverse proxy

Tags: java, routes, apache-camel, reverse-proxy

Can Apache Camel be used as a reverse proxy? I'm aware that camel is a routing engine and can be used to consume messages from different kinds of endpoints/ components. However i'm not sure whether camel can be used for the following requirement?

- when requests coming to `/context-root`, consume from this REST endpoint
- and invoke another rest service `/new-context-root` with same request params
- then send response of `/new-context-root` as the response to `/context-root`

Is this possible with camel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly possible. Although let me first say that acting as an API proxy is not Camel's main contextual use, but it can be used in the case you are describing.

A simple example (though you need to "clean the code").

```
from("restlet:http://localhost:80" + "/context-root?restletMethods=get")
to("restlet:http://localhost:81"+"/context-root1?restletMethod=get);
```

You can create processors to change the body in between the calls or change the headers.

Comment: Thanks. So this way will /context-root get the response of /context-root1 effectively?

Comment: Yes the original caller will get the response from context-root1 request.

Comment: Seems clean, can it route url calls to secure https?

Comment: Yes it can, remember to configure your truststore.